# Apply loading state to the items that are clicked in an array - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set loader only for the item that is clicked. Currently, the problem I'm facing is, it applies loading state to all the items in the array.

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-http-u02g7?file=/src/App.js:283-803). Could anyone please help?

```
export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const cars = [{ name: "Benz" }, { name: "Jeep" }, { name: "BMW" }];

  const handleClick = () => {
    // API Call
    dispatch({ type: "SET_LOADING", loading: true });
    // Loading stops once response is recieved.
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {cars.map(({ name }) => (
        <button onClick={handleClick}>
          {state.loading ? "Loading..." : name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You need to add some index for these buttons. If you don't plan to change their order you can simply use second parameter in .map callback - index. Then save in your state which id is in loading state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having a boolean ,you could use the name of the car for the loading property & then checking the value of loading property should suffice.I am assuming names are unique,otherwise add an id property & check with it.

```
import { useReducer } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const initialState = {
  loading: false
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_LOADING":
      return { ...state, loading: action.loading };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const cars = [{ name: "Benz" }, { name: "Jeep" }, { name: "BMW" }];

  const handleClick = (e,name) => {
    // API Call
    dispatch({ type: "SET_LOADING", loading: name });
    // Loading stops once response is recieved.
    // Assing loading = '' once response is received
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {cars.map(({ name }) => (
        <button onClick={(e)=>{handleClick(e,name)}}>
          {state.loading===name ? "Loading..." : name}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```